# Missing required parameter for [Route: edit-pegawai] [URI: edit-pegawai/{id}]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

I am new to Laravel, and while using the below code, it throws me 'undefined variable $id'

Below is my blade.php

```
@foreach ($dtPegawai as $p)
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ $p->nip }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $p->nama }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $p->alamat }}</td>
                  <td>{{ date('d-m-Y', strtotime($p->tgl_msk))  }}</td>
                  @if(auth()->user()->level=='admin')
                  <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('edit-pegawai',[$p->id]) }}"><i class="icon fas fa-edit fa-1x" style="color:royalblue;"></i></a> | <a href="{{ route('hapus-pegawai',$p->id) }}"><i class="icon fas fa-trash fa-1x" style="color:crimson;" alt="Hapus"></i></a>
                  </td>
                  @endif
                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

this is my Route:

```
`Route::get('/edit-pegawai/{id}',[PegawaiController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit-pegawai');`
```

and below is my Controller:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $dtPegawai = Pegawai::find($id);
        return view('halamandepan.edit-pegawai', compact('dtPegawai'));
    }
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: [$p->id] -> ["id" => $p->id]

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to SO ... in your Controller `$dtPegawai` is a single object not a collection ... in the view that you are passing it to you are trying to iterate it which would give you the properties of the Model instance

Comment: @lagbox so what should i do? im new with laravel

Comment: i cant do edit and delete data